# Finding the equation of the ellipse given the area and making a guess about the shape of the ellipse with maximum area

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections, area

The standard form of the ellipse with the foci on the x-axis

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1,\ a+b=20$$

Given the formula for the area of ellipse is

$$A=\pi ab$$

a) How do I find the area of the ellipse as a function of $a$?

b) I want to know the equation of an ellipse given the area of $264\ cm^2$
c) I was asked to complete the table based from part(a), and make a guess about the shape of the ellipse

| a | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |

| A | _ | _ | _ | _ |

Where a is the function, and A is the area.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: $a$ and $b$ play symmetric roles in all of the equations, so without doing any work, a reasonable guess for the maximal area ellipse is $a=b$. That this might give a maximum is also hinted at by the fact that as you increase either $a$ or $b$, the ellipse gets closer and closer to being a line segment.

Answer (score 0):

For part a), you can use the fact that $b=20-a$ (or that $a = 20-b$).

For the table in part b), compare the ellipse to $x^2+y^2=1$. Now, using the transformation $x \rightarrow \frac{x}{8}$, the ellipse is *squished* by a factor of $\frac{1}{8}$ in the $x$-axis, or *stretched* by a factor of $8$.

In addition, by the transformation $y \rightarrow \frac{y}{12}$, the ellipse is *stretched* by a factor of $12$ in the $y$-axis. Therefore, the ellipse will be taller than it is wide. You should fill in the table from here.

To find the ellipse that has an area of $264 \text{cm}^2$, you can use $b=20-a$ to get $\pi a(20-a) = 264$. This is a simple quadratic equation. Now solve for $a$, and then using $b=20-a$ you can solve for $b$.

Comment: Upon using the quadratic formula, it yields two positive results: 6 and 14. Which one should I use?

Comment: Either one is fine. $a=6$ gives $b=14$, and $a=14$ gives $b=6$. These have different dimensions but still give the same area.

Comment: Also I suppose you mean that the area is $264 \pi \ \text{cm}^2$ not $264 \ \text{cm}^2$.

Comment: Oh, it was a typo. Could you clarify the transformation part. I didn't quite get it.

Comment: The transformations part is from [function transformations](https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Algebra1/FunctionGraphs/FNGTransformationFunctions.html) in general. If you scroll down to the 'horizontal stretch' part, $f(kx)$ is horizontally compressed whenever $k > 1$, and stretched whenever $0 < k < 1$.

Comment: In addition, $\frac{x^2}{a^2} = (\frac{x}{a})^2$. If $f(x) = x^2$, then $f(x/a) =  (\frac{x}{a})^2$. From the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, applying the transformation of the $x$-axis, then the $y$-axis transformation gives an ellipse.

Comment: So, I have to substitute all the values of a from the table to the equation of the circle (only on the x axis).

Answer (score 0):

**First question**

Since $$a+b=20$$ you have that $$b=20-a$$. Therefore the area A is given by

$$
A = \pi a\left( {20 - a} \right)
$$

**Second question**

You have to solve the second degree equation
$$
\pi a\left( {20 - a} \right) = 264
$$
which turn to be
$$
a^2  - 20a + \frac{{264}}
{\pi } = 0
$$
You get two solutions

$$
\begin{gathered}
  a_1  = 10 + \sqrt {100 - \frac{{264}}
{\pi }}  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
  a_2  = 10 - \sqrt {100 - \frac{{264}}
{\pi }}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
Geometrically this means that you get two ellipses: one of them has the major axis on x-axis the other on the y-axis.

**Third question**
You have only to substitute and find the values of A. For the shape

1. As long as $$0<a<10$$ your ellipse has the major axis on y-axis.
2. As long as $$10<a<20$$ your ellipse has the major axis on x-axis.
3. With a=10 your ellipse turn to be a circle with the biggest area.